# SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services failure

Tags: reporting, sql-server-2014

I have a server that is also a domain controller running 2012 R2. I have successfully installed SQL Server 2014 with native reporting services. However, when I go to the web server .../reportserver I get this:

An internal error occurred on the report server. See the error log for more details. (rsInternalError) Get Online Help
The requested operation cannot be completed. The computer must be trusted for delegation and the current user account must be configured to allow delegation. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80090345)

I installed using the defaults

I'm also getting this event:

Report Server (MSSQLSERVER) cannot connect to the report server database.

and the database looks fine.

Comment: I really don't understand why people install Line of Business Applications on Domain Controllers. Domain Controllers are meant to provide and support AD DS and DNS (DHCP and Print Services are also fine). It's not meant to host and provide applications such as SQL Server, Exchange Server, etc. - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.120).aspx#DC_support

Comment: I know, I've just got a little server that sits on the floor next to my desk, If I had another box I'd use it :-). I thought of going virtual but I don't have much memory, mea cupla

Comment: I can't stress enough what a mistake it was to install SQL on a DC.  The inbox virtualization isn't memory dependent. The best advice is to try to remove sql (I'm not sure you can without having to rebuild the DC), create VMs to host DC and SQL servers and see if you still get the issue.

Comment: Having SQL on a DC is bad enough, but if you must ...did you go through the reporting services configuration? It actually has some setup required.

Comment: Thank you everyone, @joeqwerty's reference fixed the problem. I promise to save up and buy a bigger server and virtualise it all.

Comment: One reason to put SQL Server on a DC is to install CRM over it.

Comment: Funnilly enough that's exactly what I was trying to do :-)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround:
To work around this problem, set the value of the **ProtectionPolicy** registry entry to 1 to enable local backup of the MasterKey instead of requiring a RWDC in the following registry subkey:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Protect\Providers\df9d8cd0-1501-11d1-8c7a-00c04fc297eb